# Is there a way in IIS to limit calls to certain extent PER USER?

Tags: http, iis, iis-7.5

I wanted to know if there is a way in IIS to limit calls per user? Say A user can only make 100 calls per minute. If a user "foo" makes 100 calls in less than one minute they are stopped from making calls there on.

but if user "bar" is making < 100 calls per minute he should not be blocked

Any way to set that up in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

It is the web application itself who should set such limits,

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcThrottle/

Comment: excellent, looks like what i want, i am going to give it a try and let you know. thanks!

Comment: Please contact its author to see whether SignalR is supported.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know no. But you can do bitrate throttling:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/bit-rate-throttling

Maybe that will help.